# How to install and import Python modules at runtime

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I want to write a script to automatically setup a brand new ubuntu installation and install a django-based app. Since the script will be run on a new server, the Python script needs to automatically install some required modules.

Here is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import os
import sys

def pip_install(mod):
    print subprocess.check_output("pip install %s" % mod, shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.getuid() != 0:
        print "Sorry, you need to run the script as root."
        sys.exit()

    try:
        import pexpect
    except:
        pip_install('pexpect') 
        import pexpect        

    # More code here...
```

The installation of `pexpect` is success, however the next line `import pexpect` is failed. I think its because at runtime the code doesn't aware about the newly installed `pexpect`.

How to install and import Python modules at runtime? I'm open to another approaches.

Comment: untested: `pexpect = __import__('pexpect')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem using the [`imp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pip
import imp

def install_and_load(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

    path = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

    f, fname, desc = imp.find_module(package)
    return imp.load(package, f, fname, desc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        import pexpect
    except:
        pexpect = install_and_load('pexpect')

    # More code...
```

Actually the code is less than ideal, since I need to hardcode the Python module directory. But since the script is intended for a known target system, I think that is ok.

Answer (score 14):

You can import pip instead of using subprocess:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import pexpect
    except ImportError:
        install('pexpect')
        import pexpect
```

Another take:

```
import pip

def import_with_auto_install(package):
    try:
        return __import__(package)
    except ImportError:
        pip.main(['install', package])
    return __import__(package)

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pexpect = import_with_auto_install('pexpect')
    print(pexpect)
```

[edit]

You should consider using a [requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) along with pip. Seems like you are trying to automate deployments (and this is good!), in my tool belt I have also virtualenvwrapper, [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and [ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/application-deployment/).

This is the output for me:

```
(test)root@vagrant:~/test# pip uninstall pexpect
Uninstalling pexpect:
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ANSI.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ANSI.pyc
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/FSM.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/FSM.pyc
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fdpexpect.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/fdpexpect.pyc
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py2.6.egg-info
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.pyc
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pxssh.pyc
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/screen.py
  /usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/screen.pyc
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pexpect
(test)root@vagrant:~/test# python test.py
Downloading/unpacking pexpect
  Downloading pexpect-2.4.tar.gz (113Kb): 113Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pexpect
Installing collected packages: pexpect
  Running setup.py install for pexpect
Successfully installed pexpect
Cleaning up...
<module 'pexpect' from '/usr/lib/python-environments/test/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pexpect.pyc'>
(test)root@vagrant:~/test#
```

Comment: The problem still persists: the installation is success, but the import generates `ImportError: no module named pexpect`.

Comment: No, I write and run the script on new ubuntu installation. It only has `python-pip` package installed.

Comment: `WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip` looks like this approach is deprecated now. See [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599)

Answer (score 7):

For those who are using pip version greater than 10.x, there is no `main` function for `pip` so the alternative approach is using `import pip._internal as pip` instead of `import pip` like :

## Updated answer of [Paulo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234762/how-to-install-and-import-python-modules-at-runtime#answer-17234979)

```
import pip._internal as pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        import pexpect
    except ImportError:
        install('pexpect')
        import pexpect
```

Answer (score 3):

I actually made a module for this exact purpose ([impstall](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/impstall))

It's really easy to use:

```
import impstall
impstall.now('pexpect')
impstall.now('wx', pipName='wxPython')
```

[Github link for issues/contributions](https://github.com/ryanniehaus/impstall)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but none of Google's searches helped. After hours debugging, I found that it may be because the `sys.path` is not reloaded with new installation directory.

In my case on my Ubuntu Docker, I want to `import dns.resolver` at runtime for Python3.8 (pre-installed). I also created `ubuntu` user and run all things with this user (including my Python script).

- Before installing, `sys.path` doesn't have `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` since I didn't install anything.
- While installing with `subprocess` or `pip.main` like above, it creates `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` (as user installation).
- After installing , the `sys.path` should be refreshed to include this new location.

Since the `sys.path` is managed by `site` module, we should reload it (ref [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384922/how-to-refresh-sys-path)):

```
    import site
    from importlib import reload
    reload(site)
```

The full block for anyone that needs:

```
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    import dns.resolver
except ImportError:
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "dnspython"])
    import site
    from importlib import reload
    reload(site)
    import dns.resolver
```

I'm not Python developer so these code can be simplify more. This may help in cases such as fresh CI/CD environment for DevOps engineers like me.

Comment: Man thank you so much, I spent so much time searching on how to circumvent this issue. Everybody seemed to install and import just fine, but I was getting the ImportError like you mentioned.