# ImportError: No module named numpy on spark workers

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

Launching pyspark in client mode. `bin/pyspark --master yarn-client --num-executors 60` The import numpy on the shell goes fine but it fails in the kmeans. Somehow the executors do not have numpy installed is my feeling. I didnt find any good solution anywhere to let workers know about numpy. I tried setting PYSPARK_PYTHON but that didnt work either.

```
import numpy
features = numpy.load(open("combined_features.npz"))
features = features['arr_0']
features.shape
features_rdd = sc.parallelize(features, 5000)
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel

from numpy import array
from math import sqrt
clusters = KMeans.train(features_rdd, 2, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

Stack trace

```
 org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop/3/scratch/local/usercache/ajkale/appcache/application_1451301880705_525011/container_1451301880705_525011_01_000011/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/hadoop/3/scratch/local/usercache/ajkale/appcache/application_1451301880705_525011/container_1451301880705_525011_01_000011/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/hadoop/3/scratch/local/usercache/ajkale/appcache/application_1451301880705_525011/container_1451301880705_525011_01_000011/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
  File "/hadoop/3/scratch/local/usercache/ajkale/appcache/application_1451301880705_525011/container_1451301880705_525011_01_000011/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>

ImportError: No module named numpy

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        enter code here
```

Comment: Can you access the machines the workers are running on and check if your `PYSPARK_PYTHON` indeed has numpy?

Comment: Also, just as a precaution, make sure the py file itself is not named "numpy."

Comment: @Snoozer unfortunately i cannot access the workers in this yarn setup.

Comment: @abe there is no py file. I dump these on the spark shell.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that NumPy is installed on worker nodes? If not tinkering with path won't help you. While PySpark provide mechanisms of distributing dependencies it is unlikely to help you with complex packages like NumPy (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34385088/1560062).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To use Spark in Yarn client mode, you'll need to install any dependencies to the machines on which Yarn starts the executors. That's the only surefire way to make this work.

Using Spark with Yarn cluster mode is a different story. You can distribute python dependencies with spark-submit.

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster my_script.py --py-files my_dependency.zip
```

However, the situation with numpy is complicated by the same thing that makes it so fast: the fact that does the heavy lifting in C. Because of the way that it is installed, you won't be able to distribute numpy in this fashion.

Comment: so if understand it right, numpy has to be installed on each executor and cannot be distributed ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. My team and I have been bitten by this exact problem.

Comment: Thanks @dayman, this helps! I got around to implement it in scala. I wish there is a better solution for this pyspark issue though.

Comment: Would it be possible to package all the dependencies into a `virtualenv`, compress and dump it on each node of the cluster? Although I am aware this could become extremely heavy, would that work?

Comment: tried  packaging all the dependencies into a virtualenv and passed still same issue

Answer (score 5):

numpy is not installed on the worker (virtual) machines. If you use anaconda, it's very convenient to upload such python dependencies when deploying the application in cluster mode. (So there is no need to install numpy or other modules on each machine, instead they must in your anaconda).
Firstly, zip your anaconda and put the zip file to the cluster, and then you can submit a job using following script.

```
 spark-submit \
 --master yarn \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --archives hdfs://host/path/to/anaconda.zip#python-env
 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=pthon-env/anaconda/bin/python 
 app_main.py
```

Yarn will copy anaconda.zip from the hdfs path to each worker, and use that pthon-env/anaconda/bin/python to execute tasks.

Refer to [Running PySpark with Virtualenv](https://henning.kropponline.de/2016/09/17/running-pyspark-with-virtualenv/) may provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me (On `mac`) was actually this guide (Which also explains how to run python through `Jupyter Notebooks` - 
https://medium.com/@yajieli/installing-spark-pyspark-on-mac-and-fix-of-some-common-errors-355a9050f735

In a nutshell:
(Assuming you installed spark with `brew install spark`)

1. Find the `SPARK_PATH` using - `brew info apache-spark`
2. Add those lines to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Spark and Python
######
export SPARK_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.1
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
#For python 3, You have to add the line below or you will get an error
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
alias snotebook='$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]'
######
```

3. You should be able to open `Jupyter Notebook` simply by calling:
   `pyspark`

And just remember you don't need to set the `Spark Context` but instead simply call:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I believe you are running spark locally, as standalone application like this, not on cluster.

Answer (score 1):

For me environment variable `PYSPARK_PYTHON` was not set so I set up `/etc/environment` file and added python environment path to the variable.

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/venv/python3
```

Afterwards, no such error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but I dont think you need to set PYSPARK_PYTHON instead just install numpy on the worker machine (apt-get or yum). The error will also tell you on which machine the import was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that you need to have numpy installed on each and every worker, and even the master itself (depending on your component placement)
Also ensure to launch `pip install numpy` command from a root account (sudo does not suffice) after forcing umask to 022 (`umask 022`) so it cascades the rights to Spark (or Zeppelin) User

Answer (score 0):

A few of things to check

- Install the required packages on the worker nodes with sudo permission so that they are available to all users
- If you have multiple versions of the python on the worker nodes, make sure to install packages for python used by Spark (usually set by PYSPARK_PYTHON).
- Finally, to pass the custom modules (.py files), use --py-files while starting the session using spark-submit or pyspark

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Try installing numpy on pip3 if you're using Python3

`pip3 install numpy`

Comment: first make sure pyspark is effectively using Python3