# Spark ImportError: No module named *

Tags: python, apache-spark

why when i use `rdd = rdd.map(lambda i: Recommendation.TransfertRecurrentConfigKey(i))` i got this errors

```
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 161, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named Recommendation.Recommendation
```

and when i use this `rdd = rdd.map( Recommendation.TransfertRecurrentConfigKey)`, the code work well ? 
if i ask that is because i want to be able to past in argument the list of key `["Sexe", "Age", "Profession", "Revenus"]`.

```
class Recommendation:
@staticmethod
def TransfertRecurrentRecommendation(dataFrame):
    rdd = dataFrame.rdd.map(Recommendation.TransfertRecurrentCleanData)
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x is not None)

    #rdd = rdd.map(lambda user: ((user['Sexe'], user['Age'], user['Profession'], user['Revenus']), user['TransfertRecurrent']))
    rdd = rdd.map(lambda i: Recommendation.TransfertRecurrentConfigKey(i))
    print rdd.collect()

@staticmethod
def TransfertRecurrentConfigKey(user):
    tmp = []
    for k in ["Sexe", "Age", "Profession", "Revenus"]:
        tmp.append(user[k])
    return tuple(tmp), user['TransfertRecurrent']
```

> EDIT : i solved the errors, but i still don't understand why in first case it works and it doesn't work in the second.
>   (See the second answer [ImportError: No module named numpy on spark workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214231/importerror-no-module-named-numpy-on-spark-workers))

Comment: How did you solve your problem ?